# Hibernate display query in the console

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to see the sql queries that are executed by hibernate, so I have:

```
AnnotationConfiguration hibernateConfig = new AnnotationConfiguration();
...//configuring the data url, user, etc.
hibernateConfig.setProperty("show_sql", "true");
hibernateConfig.setProperty("format_sql", "true");
```

It is hard to find the correct property names, so I used the same name as I would use in the xml file, but I don't find any outputs to the log.

Is it anything else that I need to do, besides adding the above two lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prefix property names with `hibernate`

```
hibernateConfig.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
hibernateConfig.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
hibernateConfig.setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments", "true");
```

The property `hibernate.use_sql_comments` to show corresponding HQL

And you can set this properties in the `hibernate.properties` of course

```
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
```